# Blender crashing when opening file on Mac

Tags: osx

I'm having an issue while trying to open an otherwise perfectly fine project in Blender 2.83 on my iMac Pro (macOS Catalina). The file worked perfectly last week, now, when trying to open it, Blender crashes. Another similar project (duplicated) works perfectly. I haven't changed anything and the last time I had Blender open was with the file that is now crashing. How can I fix this issue, as this is a client project that I cannot access any longer?

Thanks!